# is there any cuda miner

Tags: mining

I have a Nvidia Geforce GT 650T version 369.09 with 4Go memory, i want to try mining ethereum using a Cuda based miner, i've read that geth and eth didn't support cuda so is there any fork or another miner to use it? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genoil's ethminer is what you're looking for.  CUDA mining with some nice extra features.

https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently on a machine equipped with an Nvidia GTX950 and I'm GPU mining via the command

```
$ ethminer -G
```

To install it you have to install cpp-ethereum, here are the steps under ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cpp-ethereum
```

or directly via github: [cpp-ethereum on github](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum)